# Can an iPad be charged faster with a third party power adapter?

Tags: ipad

I recently came into possession of a Samsung usb charger. This charger has double the power output of the standard apple one (5Vx2A instead of 1A). Of course, it would be nice to decrease the charging time of my iPad (3rd gen) with this adapter. Since I don't have the equipment to measure the power consumption of an iPad during charging I can't produce reliable data on this issue.

I was wondering if somebody ever studied the charging times of mobile apple devices (most notably the iPad) with third-party chargers and could share some  data (like power consumption, charging times, ...) on it.

Comment: I don't think the iPad draws more than 1A from any charger. But it'd be interesting to experiment with a 2A or greater charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard iPad charger is 2.1Amp at 5V. The 1amp is for iPhone and charges slowly, or not at all if you're using it at the same time.

The 2Amp one will charge it much faster. Works very well with iPhones too.

http://gizmodo.com/5535631/the-fastest-and-slowest-way-to-charge-an-ipad

Comment: Just what I wanted, thank you. (Now I'm embarrassed that I didn't find this page myself :-))

Comment: The current iPad charger is 5.2 V/2.4 A (12 W); the original charger was 5.1 V/2.1 A (10 W).  The Retina iPads have a much larger battery and take a lot longer to charge as a result, as the charging speed has not increased proportionally.  You can see pictures of both of them here: http://assets.ilounge.com/images/reviews_apple/12wusb/8.jpg. (I'm not sure if the iPad 1/2/mini will benefit from the 2.4 A charger.)

Answer (score 0):

You can drain your device and time the charge rate with the device powered off or in airplane mode with a wrist watch.

Th consumption can be controlled by powering off the device as soon as you see it running and charging. Placing it in airplane mode and powering it off also ensures that no significant CPU or network activity can drain power over the normal idle sleep power consumption.

In a test with putting the device in airplane mode and powering it off, you can en charge it to full and expect between 25 and 45 days of idle power in a fully charged battery with no additional charging. This low level of consumption might change your full charge time by tens of seconds at Mose over a totally idle and shut off device.